# Python Selenium Loop thru groups in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, selenium

I have a table like this

```
Winner | Group_ID 
Joe.   |     1
Mike.  |     1
Peter. |     1
John.  |     2
Leon.  |     2
Kraus. |     2
```

And now I need a query to loop through all records where group_id is 1, then 2, then 3, etc. After each group, selenium is clicking a submit button. So to review, I need to grab all data from the table where group id 1 then click submit. Then grab all data where group ID is 2 then submit. Etc.

Here my attempt:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table GROUP by group_id"

mycursor.execute(sql)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for row in myresult:
  print(row[0])
  thewinner = row[0]
  thegroupip = row[1]

  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='myclass'][contains(text(),'"+thewinner+"')]").click()
```

Grouping by ID only gives me 1 record. I tried to Select DISTINCT but I'm only getting 1 record.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need grouping in this case. It will be enough to order records by group_id and keep track of the previous record while iterating. It will allow you to check the change of the group_id and perform click using data from previous row.

Here is an example:

```
sql = "select winner, group_id from table order by group_id"

mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

prev_group_id = None
prev_winner = None

for row in myresult:
  print(row[0])
  thewinner = row[0]
  thegroupip = row[1]

  if prev_group_id is None:
    prev_group_id = thegroupip

  if prev_group_id != thegroupip:
    prev_group_id = thegroupip
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='myclass'][contains(text(),'" + prev_winner + "')]").click()

  prev_winner = thewinner
```